# Singular vs. plural when the subject has multiple objects in it

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, sentence-patterns

This is a question about deciding singular vs. plural verb where the subject contains multiple objects in it. Let me set the context first.

I have a mathematical problem where I need to find a solution to a problem. A single solution is a collection of three functions I need to find. For examples, the functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x + 1 and h(x) = 3x + 2 may form a single solution. Similarly, the functions f(x) = x + 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = 0 may form yet another solution.

Now after solving the problem I find that there is only solution to the problem. Which of the following ways is the right way to express this thought?

1. The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 is the only solution to the given problem.
2. The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x, h(x) = x + 2 is the only solution to the given problem.
3. The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 are the only solutions to the given problem.

Option 3 sounds grammatically correct to me but sounds mathematically incorrect to me because the functions f(x), g(x) and h(x) are not three different solutions I have found to the problem. Those 3 functions together constitute a single solution to the given problem.

So is option 1 or option 2 correct? If none of the options are correct, what is a correct way to express this thought?

Comment: It needs rephrasing. << The only solution to the given problem is when the functions in question are defined as follows: f(x) = 1; g(x) = 2x; h(x) = x + 2 >> (and I'd use bullet-points).

Comment: While rephrasing the sentence is definitely one way, I want to understand if English grammar already accounts for a situation like this. Does English grammar allow anyway to write something similar to one of the three options I presented with minor tweaks? I am trying to understand if there is a way to express "X, Y and Z is ..." where we know from the context that "X, Y and Z" constitute of a single instance of something.

Comment: Notional agreement is certainly used (at least to some extent) by many if not most proficient Anglophones. 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal' / 'Health and safety is our primary concern'. But your suggestions here are at least bordering on the outlandish, and  should be rewritten in accordance with Orwell's Sixth (Rule): 'avoid anything sounding outlandish, even if you have to resort to a breech in grammaticality' (a fair paraphrase).

Comment: Apples, oranges and grapes are the fruit to eat. So, the answer is yes. This is not even a math question, really. The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 are the only solutions to the given problem. RIGHT.

Comment: The copula *is* just isn't up to the job. You need a verb with semantic content such as *composed of*.  The only solution is composed of the functions ...

Comment: "Lambie No; the comparison is infelicitous. Unlike '[a]pples, oranges and grapes', '[t]he functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2' here is a deleted form (from say 'the functions f, g and h **being defined** thus: f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2') and, if persisted with, strongly attracts singular agreement (The men being absent is a real problem). It's messy and far better rewritten.

Comment: I'd prefer "The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 are the only solution to the given problem." This indicates there is a single solution, but it's more natural to have verb agree with subject than object. (Compare: "Fleas are a pain to deal with" or "Tom and Jerry are an eternal dyad".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1 or 2 will do but the following should be added. The multiple functions you list make up a *Set* of functions. You have found that only one set of functions make a solution.

"The *set* of functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 is the only solution to the given problem."

It is common to use *and* in place of the last comma separating an enumerated list. You may even use both as in "g(x) = 2x, and h(x) = x + 2" according to Warner's English Grammar.

Comment: I disagree. I could accept  _f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x ,/and h(x) = x + 2_ is the only solution to the given problem. Or your 'The set of ...'. But 1 and 2 sound outlandish.

Comment: Sorry, I added a comma to this answer by mistake (and then removed it).

Comment: @DjinTonic; You and Oscar Wilde. Maybe switch to Absinthe.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it sounds more natural to say *x = 10, y = 20, and z = 15 **is** the/a solution* when asked to find, say, three values in a problem. Therefore:

> *(Functions) f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x, and h(x) = x + 2 is the only solution to the given problem.*

(assuming that together they constitute **one solution**). "Functions" can be omitted if you like.

Or you could say

> *The system of functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x, and h(x) = x + 2  is the only solution.*

(Just as we refer to a *system of equations*).

---

> Thus selecting arbitrarily a partial **system of functions**  of the
> observations... we can ... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theory_of_Observations/xm5tAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=what%20is%20a%20%22system%20of%20functions%22&pg=PA58&printsec=frontcover)

> Clearly, if each function in a given set of generators belongs to a
> closed system F, then the **system of functions** generated by those
> generators is contained in F.  [Emil Post; *The Two-Values Iterative
> System of Mathematical Logic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Two_Valued_Iterative_Systems_of_Math/i9HfCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=what%20is%20a%20%22system%20of%20functions%22&pg=PA14&printsec=frontcover) p.14

> Let ... be a **system of functions** defined on some measurable subset
> ... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theory_and_Applications_of_Differentiabl/QBEUElCvMNgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=what%20is%20a%20%22system%20of%20functions%22&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score -2):

> The functions f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2 **are** the only solutions to the given problem.

This is the only correct version.

"f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2" stand in apposition to "functions". As such they do not influence the plurality of the subject which is "functions."

**Functions** is plural therefore the verb is "are".

Comment: Would you say 'x = 2, y = 3 and z = 4 are the only solution to the problem'?  I'll not add to the downvote, but the only sensible answer is to rewrite.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the mathematics have clouded the issue for you. It might help if you omit them *Would I say 'x = 2, y = 3 and z = 4 are the only solution to the problem'?* Why do you ask, as I never said that? You yourself would say "**These** are  the only solutions to the problem'? There is no need to rewrite.

Comment: No I wouldn't. The solution, the single solution, is {f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2x and h(x) = x + 2}. Here the solution set comprises three defined functions. A more typical solution set consisting of numbers is: the single solution to the simultaneous linear equations x + y = 4, x - 2y = 1 is {x = 3, y = 1}. I've still not added a downvote, though I see a second person has.